# Proving that $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{n!}{20^n} = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } n > N \Rightarrow \left| \frac{1}{a_n} \right| < \epsilon$$

If this is true, we know that the sequence ${a_n}$ diverges as $ n \rightarrow \infty$

I got stuck in this proof as I want to show that:

$$\left|\frac{20^n}{n!}\right| < \epsilon$$

by a line of inequalities, I can state that $$\frac{20^n}{n!} < 20^n < \epsilon \Rightarrow -n > -\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(20)}$$

Using Python this result gives nonsensical answers, it's obvious it would be from the equation as it's not true for all $N$... Does anyone have any advice on how to go about fixing it? Thank you!

Furthermore, I cannot use any tests it has to be a proof by definition.

Comment: Please use the appropriate commands "\log" and "\lim" for logarithms and limits.

Comment: Hint: For $n\geq 39,$ $a_{n+1}\geq 2a_n.$

Comment: You're certainly not going to show that $20^n<\epsilon$ for arbitrarily large $n$.  Also if you did somehow show that (which you can't because it's false), you would be done.  Finally, if you were to continue reasoning after that, you would not conclude  $n > -\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(20)}$, you would  conclude $n < \frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(20)}$, or if for some strange reason you wanted to reverse the inequality you would have $-n>-\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(20)}$.

Comment: Generally you need to be more careful not to throw too much away when you develop an inequality. Like here, it is true that if you replace $n!$ with $1$ then you get something bigger, but you also now have something that doesn't go to zero anymore, so your observation is true but useless. Instead, somehow you want to replace $n!$ with something smaller (and simpler) that is still way bigger than $20^n$ if $n$ is big enough. Since $n!$ is a product of a bunch of stuff, you can consider replacing some/all of the factors in that product by smaller factors.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Given this hint I reched an answer where $N = max\{39, \frac{20}{\epsilon}\}$ Though I am not sure how to reach the hint without using programming.

Comment: @TeodorasPaura $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{20}a_n$ makes it pretty obviously without programming.

Comment: And $N=\max(39,20/\epsilon)$ won't work in general.

Comment: @TeodorasPaura, your question is a duplicate. Here is [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003233/771461).

Comment: @Angelo The question presented uses a definition rather than intuitive or other advanced methods in your linked question.

Comment: Does this (more elementary) answer your question? [prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a^n}{n!}}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828346/prove-lim-n-to-infty-fracann-0) See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/992086) or [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696947). All found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim%5Cfrac%7Ba%5En%7D%7Bn!%7D%3D0%24&p=1), but there are probably more in that link.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{20}a_n,$ and thus, for $n\geq 40,$ $a_{n+1}> 2a_n,$ for $n\geq 40.$

Then $a_n>2^{n-40}a_{40}$ for $n> 40.$ To get $a_n>\frac1\epsilon,$ you need $$n-40> \log_2\frac1{a_{40}\epsilon}$$

So you can take $$N=40+\max\left(0,-\log_2(a_{40}\epsilon)\right).$$

You can get a trivial bound $a_{40}>\frac1{20^{40}}>\frac1{32^{40}},$ so $-\log_2 a_{40}\leq 200.$ You can do much better than this with a better estimate of $a_{40},$ but you don't need it.
Then you can use:

$$N=40+\max(0,200-\log_2\epsilon).$$

Comment: How did you get the intuition to write $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{20}a_n$

Comment: @AkashArjun $a_n=\frac{n!}{20^n}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)!}{20^{n+1}}=\frac{n!}{20^n}\cdot\frac{n+1}{20}$ hence $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{20}a_{n}$.

Comment: The fundamental definition of $n!$ is $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!,$ and $20^n$ has a similar recursion.. @AkashArjun

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was a bit confused so took a while to deduce but thank you for the answer!